# Uncheck checkbox in Leaflet Layercontrol when removing layer

Tags: leaflet

When I remove a layer, which is a overlay in the layerControl, with the function `map.removeLayer(layerName);` the layer is removed from the map as expected.

However the checkbox for this layer in the layerControl is still checked. Is there an easy leaflet function to uncheck the box without the need to remove and re-add the layer to the layerControl or somehow fiddle around with unchecking this checkbox via Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

I found this a problem as well.

My goal was: any time the basemap was changed, toggle a labelling overlay layer off.

To do this I used the following which i consider just a hack but sufficient:

```js
map.on('baselayerchange', function (e) {
  // console.log('test')
  // map.removeLayer(CartoDB_VoyagerOnlyLabels)

  var overlayCb = document.querySelector("#map > div.leaflet-control-container > div.leaflet-bottom.leaflet-left > div.leaflet-control-layers.leaflet-control > section > div.leaflet-control-layers-overlays > label > div > input");

  //console.log(overlayCb.checked)

  if (overlayCb.checked){overlayCb.click()};

});
```

Some notes:

The commented `removeLayer` line worked for turning off the layer, but the checkbox remained checked, which is really unacceptable.

I had to use the brutal element path in querySelector because the radio input's are not given id's or helpful classes when leaflet creates them. Maybe there is a good way to set those id's.

If multiple overlay layers are used, it may be necessary to pick one from an array of them returned by that selector. I haven't tested this.

Last, this is using leaflet version 1.6. Maybe this is fixed in a more recent version of leaflet. I'm not in a position to upgrade currently.